# Scheme: Count number of lambda symbols in function

Tags: lambda, count, scheme

So we had taken a test over Scheme and I got one of the problems wrong, but I have no idea how to correct it.  What it asks for is:

write a Scheme function count_lambda which takes an arbitrary expression, y, and returns the number of 'lambda symbols in y.  For example, invoking (count_lambda '(lambda x . lambda y . x y) z) should return 2.

The way I thought of for how to do this was to check to see if the variable was of type "lambda".  However, lambda might not be a type....... Also, I pictured the expression being a list.... not sure if I can do that either...so this is what I have:

```
 (define count_lambda
  (lambda (y)
    (if (null? y) 0
    (cond
      ((lambda? y) 1)
      ((number? y) 0)
      ((cons? y) (+ (count_lambda(car y)) (count_lambda(cdr y)))))))
```

It says lambda is an undefined function so that right there tells me I'm looking at it wrong.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what I should do for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The sample input you provided isn't correct, it has parentheses problems and this: `x.lambda` looks like an error, perhaps you meant `x . lambda`? Please check and fix it.

Comment: it looks like there's no space, but maybe.  What is the difference?

Comment: it makes all the difference in the world. `x.lambda` is not a `lambda` symbol, whereas `x . lambda` _contains_ a `lambda` symbol. It's very important that you provide correct input, even with the proper spaces in place, the sample you gave won't compile, it's an invalid expression, because of misplaced dots and parentheses

Comment: Ok, didn't know that.  And I see the parenthesis wrong; I just figured that what she gave us to enter was correct.  To me, it looks like there should be one in between the x and the y?

Comment: Wait a second, I shouldn't be adding parenthesis

Comment: I removed the last one.  Just let me know if that's wrong.  I'm not exactly an expert with Scheme.

Comment: Try typing the input list in the Scheme interpreter. The moment it _works_, come back and update the question. The current code, even after the update, won't work. For example: that `z` seems to be outside the input list, is it another parameter for the function? Bottom line: to get good answers, start by providing good questions

Comment: It doesn't like the spaces in between; it says illegal use of '.'.  Also, I am entering what we were given.  You typically don't say "well the input given on the test is wrong, better change it to something that makes more sense." Thirdly, I realize it doesn't run, that's why I asked it on here...

Comment: If your code isn't perfect that's not a problem, we're here to help. But if the input test you give us is wrong (and believe me, it _is_) then there isn't much anybody can do to help you. Just try typing this, it won't work, the parentheses are wrong, the dots are wrong: `(count_lambda '(lambda x . lambda y . x y) z)`

Comment: using that says it's an improper use of '.'.  And I agree, I should've double checked the parenthesis.  In reality, though, if I was told to look over and fix everything wrong with it... the only thing I would've known was wrong would be the parenthesis.

Comment: If you manage to get a correct input, you'll see that my solution works, for example try this: `(count_lambda '((lambda x lambda y x y) z))` Maybe your instructor isn't aware that the `.` character has a special meaning in lists, and you can't just write it anywhere?

Comment: well... that did work, so thanks.  But why were you able to get rid of the dots?

Comment: I believe your instructor is trying to introduce lambda calculus, which uses dots as part of its notation. But in Lisp you can't add arbitrary dots as part of a list, they have a special meaning. I simply wrote a valid list, without the dots, and I suggest you have a long talk about it with your instructor, make sure she tests the sample input before giving it to you. Teachers _do_ make mistakes, too :P

Comment: ugh... really not surprised, though.  I think I will ask considering I'm meeting with her tomorrow.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. Notice that the input is a list of *symbols*, you're required to count the number of times the symbol `'lambda` appears in the list, not the number of times an actual `lambda` appears.

Also, the template for iterating over a list of lists isn't quite right. This is how it should look like:

```
(define count_lambda
  (lambda (y)
    (cond ((null? y) 0) ; is the list empty?
          ((not (pair? y)) ; if the current element is an atom
           (if (eq? y 'lambda) 1 0)) ; then check to see if is a lambda
          (else (+ (count_lambda (car y)) ; otherwise advance recursion
                   (count_lambda (cdr y)))))))
```

Comment: Are you sure about the input being a list of symbols?  The OP wrote "write a Scheme function count_lambda which takes an arbitrary expression, y, and returns the number of 'lambda symbols in y."  It seems to me that `(lambda 234 lambda (x lambda))` would be an expression, but it's not just a list of symbols.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the sample input is quoted, unless OP states the contrary, I will assume it's a list of symbols. I don't think OP meant to use an arbitrary expression, this looks like the first steps in an introductory programming course, it wouldn't make sense (from a teaching POV) to process arbitrary expressions at this point in the course

Comment: The way it's written, I though that OP was quoting verbatim from the text.  It's almost the end of the semester in many places;  I don't think counting occurrences of `lambda` in a _tree_ (as opposed to a _list_) should be too difficult.  That said, hopefully OP will clarify.  It _does_ seem a bit more likely that the question is about lists.

Comment: Just to clarify, the class isn't based around Scheme.  It was a couple sections we went over, and it was a section on the test.  We didn't go too in depth with it.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez There's no need for the `null?` clause here.  The `(not (pair?y y))` will be true when `y` is `90`, and it won't be` eq?` to `lambda`, so  you'll still get `0`.  Only two cases are needed: pair and non-pair.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you're right, but I'd rather leave it there. It's part of the solution template, it's not necessary for this case in particular, but it is for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

[Óscar has a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20055864/1565698), but I just want to point out that using `lambda?` is not an bad idea, but you need to make it. In addition `cons?` is not a primitive in `scheme` but perhaps the cousin language `#!racket` which has it's own SO-tag.

Here is a `Scheme` implementation using the latest ratified standard R7RS:

```
#!r7rs
(import (scheme base)
        (only (scheme) display))

(define (lambda? x)
    (eq? x 'lambda))

(define (count-lambda lst)
  (cond
    ((lambda? lst) 1)
    ((not (pair? lst)) 0) ; cons? is not a scheme primitive
    (else (+ (count-lambda (car lst)) 
             (count-lambda (cdr lst))))))


(display (count-lambda '(yatta (lambda . lambda) #f #t 34 
                        (hey (ho lambda . yiu) lambda )))) ; displays 4
```

Compared to your code I have removed the check for a number (since what is not a pair or a lambda can be a different symbol, a number, #t), instead I have added a base case that actually does the same.

It will work in R6RS (since R7RS only supported by chibi and we have a lot of good R6RS-implementations like DrRacket and Ikarus by replacing the 3 first lines with:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (only (rnrs) display))
```